# What do we know about homogenous system of linear Diophantine equations?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

I am aware that in general finding solutions of system of linear Diophantine equations is difficult and theoretically an open problem. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

How about for the special case of homogenous system of linear Diophantine equations?

$$a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n=0\\
b_1x_1+\dots+b_nx_n=0\\
c_1x_1+\dots+c_nx_n=0\\
\dots$$

where we are looking for integer solutions?

Clearly $x_1=\dots=x_n=0$ is the trivial solution.

Do we know when there exists nontrivial solutions?

Thanks. (I am still interested in partial / weak results if the full result is unknown.)

Comment: Linear Diophantine equations is boring and not interesting ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a "theory" of solving systems of linear Diophantine equations, see for example the article [Linear Diophantine Equations](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~wgilbert/Research/GilbertPathria.pdf), based on the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. For further references see

[Algorithm for finding integer solutions to a system of linear Diophantine equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078707/algorithm-for-finding-integer-solutions-to-a-system-of-linear-diophantine-equati)

Comment: Are there any results that involve conditions on the coefficients, and then concluding that there exists nontrivial solutions? Thanks.